# UIManager Font Setting

Tags: swing, scala

```
   font = new Font("San Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24)
  val keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys()
  while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
   val key = keys.nextElement()
   val value = UIManager get key
   if (value.isInstanceOf[FontUIResource])
    UIManager.put(key, font)
  }
```

I used the code above to change all the default fonts in Scala Swing components. I tried with Label, TitledBorder, TextField, PasswordField and Button so far. However, Label and Button are staying the same while others are using the new font. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should override LookAndFeel instead? It is not easy though.

Comment: I did override the LookAndFeel. But I still need a bigger font size for most of the component.

Comment: Pawel, thanks anyway. It does seems to be a problem with the LookAndFeel. I changed the LookAndFeel to Metal from GTK and now the code is working just fine.