# how change font of all of my components in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

I want to change or modify font of all om my JFrame.

Like just one time I change font and all the frame font size change to new thing.

Previous time I changed look & feel of my window I think that way can, but I am looking for another solution, if any please provide an example for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679002/uimanager-font-setting

Comment: good but can u solve his problem, I mean I need to rewrite look&feel?

Comment: There is no problem to solve. Some LAF's allow you to change the font, others don't. So you choose a LAF that allows you to change the font.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: execute your code with different VM parameters:

```
java -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Tahoma -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Tahoma …
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a config file(or resource file) and when you want to changing something read the file and set values.

resource file:(Of course you can use JSON, XML or anything you want.
This is just a example)
    fontNameA: San Serif
    fontNameB: XXXX

```
fontSizeA: 20
fontSizeB: 30

backgourdImage………

class StyleProvider{
  …
  public StyleProvider(String yourConfigFilePath){
    /* read it */
  }
  public String getFontName(/* you can write some arguments here*/){
    return something;
  }
  /* other methods */
}

/* your working code */
StyleProvider sp = new StyleProvider("filepath")
font = new Font(sp.getFontName(), Font.PLAIN, sp.getFontSize());
```